# How to fetch only one element

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from api with axios, the problem that i want only one element with specific id but when i console.log i get hundred of lines of the same element

```
 constructor(props) {
    super();
    const id= props.match.params.id;
    this.state = {
        items: [],
        id: id,
    }

}

render() {
    axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({ items: res.data });
      // console.log(this.state.items);
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to get from that API? If I access that endpoint with an id, I do get only one object with many properties. For example: http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/1

Comment: i m getting the same object too many times when i show in console, ineed something to limit it , i tried http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${this.state.id}_limit=1 but its blocked by core policy

Comment: I get it. What else do you have inside your render? You will send an API request everytime there's a rendering happening, so you might want to remove that call from your render and place it inside a `componentDidMount`.

Comment: it was exactly the problem, thank u so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted an actual answer expanding on the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

A React component gets rendered if a change happens in your props or in your state. If you update your state or your props, your UI element will get updated because the function `render` will be called, which causes multiple re-renderings.

Because of that, you need to move your calls to your API from your render function to another function, since your render function will potentially be called quite a few times and you don't want to send the same request to the API quite a few times. When using a class component, you can add your API call to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function.

Answer (score 0):

Move the axios.get to `componentDidMount()` lifecycle function and out of the render.  As it currently is written, that will get called on every render, so every state, prop, or parent component render.  If you move it to inside the lifecycle method it will call the get endpoint when the component mounts, just once.